# Sql Azure Database in azure show This asset was not found, it may have been deleted but is running

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having an issue when I try change settings to Sql Azure Database at Azure, I see:

> "This asset was not found, it may have been deleted"

But the access to database by Management Studio is working.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little more background on the error? What settings are you trying to change? can you see the database on the Azure SQL Server? What does the activity log says?

Comment: I was looking my sql azure database in Resource group (i'm sure than created) but i don't see, almost i see the aplication service plan than contain , so i try to connect using Management Studio and is working but i don't see at Azure Resource Group, so i can see Activity log for that database and Activity Log for Application Service say is don't ocurrs any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who tried to help me, I did not understand at all because, but it seems that maybe it was a problem in azure as such, this problem was presented to me by 3 database, what I did was try a "madness" and was renombrar the database through the Management Studio and once completed was presented in the Azure dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

After moving my SQL Server (and it´s only database) between resource groups I had the exact same issue.

- SQL Server was listed under "All Resources".
- SQL Database had disappeared and was not listed undier "All Resources".
- I could see my database if I clicked my SQL Server -> SQL Databases. status was "Online".
- If I clicked the database I got the exact same error.

My database was always accessible from SQL Management Studio. Renaming the database in Management Studio to something different and then back to it´s previous name fixed the problem. Now it´s visible again under "All Resources".

Answer (score 0):

This error will usually happen,

- when you delete the resource and forget to refresh the page for a while

Comment: but in this case no database was deleted, in fact I still have access by the managment Studio

Comment: Then it was a permission issue. You don't have enough permission to View the DB. I think it was set in the Resouce level/Subscription level lock for particular user

Comment: I am the only user associated with the account so there is no hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The issue is usually related to invalid operations with the resource group. For example, assigning a server/database to a resource group that doesn't exist.

1. Go on your dashboard and delete any shortcut to your database and its server.
2. Go to the All resources tab on the left blade of the Azure portal and search for your database. Click on it.
3. Pin the database to the dashboard again by clicking on the pin icon on the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: That screen i can't see because when i trying select database is showing the error

Comment: Can you locate the database in the All resources search engine? Does it show up in the database list under your server panel?